# Any way to flash unpacked firmware into MiFi?

Tags: ethernet, firmware, mobile-broadband, alcatel

I bought Alcatel Linkzone MW40V from Vodafone store, but I can't access USSD codes from "More" option

[image]

It simply doesn't appear/exist and it's difficult to me remove my SIM card every time I need to check my balance or do other operations.

I discovered that firmware of others similar or little newer devices has access to USSD codes, so I need to flash the firmware in my MiFi in order to solve the issue. I don't think the hardware changed soo much.

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1bbb:0195 T & A Mobile Phones Alcatel OneTouch L850V / Telekom Speedstick LTE

Software Version:   MW40_00_02.00_25
Device Name:    MW40
IMEI:   352491109846647
MAC Address:    f0:51:36:3d:2e:18
IP Address:     192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
```

I managed to unpack the img file with help of reverse engineering community [site](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/unpacking-download-img-firmware-for-alcatel-mw40). But I don't know what to do next, pls help!

Comment: Is this about Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu... maybe it'd be easy with some python scripting of something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point to this URL at the Modem Web menu:

```
http://IPmodem/default.html#more/ussdSetting.html
```